# JavaScript Set URL according to index

Tags: javascript, html

Please help me to optimize this script :

```
$('#dynamic-menu li:nth-child(1) a').attr('href','#' + $('.cmsPanel:nth-child(2)').attr('id'));
$('#dynamic-menu li:nth-child(2) a').attr('href','#' + $('.cmsPanel:nth-child(3)').attr('id'));
$('#dynamic-menu li:nth-child(3) a').attr('href','#' + $('.cmsPanel:nth-child(4)').attr('id'));
$('#dynamic-menu li:nth-child(4) a').attr('href','#' + $('.cmsPanel:nth-child(5)').attr('id'));
$('#dynamic-menu li:nth-child(5) a').attr('href','#' + $('.cmsPanel:nth-child(6)').attr('id'));
$('#dynamic-menu li:nth-child(6) a').attr('href','#' + $('.cmsPanel:nth-child(7)').attr('id'));
```

HTML INPUT:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/randomUrl"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/yyy"></a></li>
    <li><a href="/zzz"></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="cmsTabBox">
    <ul>
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cmsPanel" id="randomUrl"></div>
    <div class="cmsPanel" id="another-random-url"></div>
    <div class="cmsPanel" id="random"></div>
</div>
```

The one above works, but how can I automatically copy the `id`, decrease index and copy it to href attribute?

HTML OUTPUT NEEDED:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#randomUrl"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#another-random-url"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#random"></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="cmsTabBox">
    <ul>
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
        <li>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cmsPanel" id="randomUrl"></div>
    <div class="cmsPanel" id="another-random-url"></div>
    <div class="cmsPanel" id="random"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't find `.cmsPanel` in your HTML.

Comment: And in this way, the `div` will not be the same `nth-child` as the `a`

Answer (score 2):

You should do `.each()` way:

```js
$('#dynamic-menu li').each(function (i) {
  $(this).find("a").attr('href','#' + $('.cmsPanel:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')').attr('id'));
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('#dynamic-menu li').each(function (i) {
    $(this).find("a").attr('href','#' + i);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<ul id="dynamic-menu">
  <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you, but sorry, it's not exactly the thing I need, as .cmsPanel id is always unique and doesn't have any logic, the only consistent thing is logic

Comment: @user3497585 Can you show me your HTML code as well. Would be helpful. Also tell me what you wanna get out of it.

Comment: @user3497585 I guess you need to refresh the page. Check it out. I have edited twice already.

Comment: This one also creates #undefined href value

Comment: @user3497585 There's no `.cmsPanel`!

Comment: ouh, sorry, I just updated my HTML (forgot to add to snippet)

Comment: @user3497585 Or better use `cmsPanel:nth-of-type` instead of `.cmsPanel:nth-child`. Demo: http://jsbin.com/qobixuyidu/

Answer (score 2):

Using `each` :

**Before Edit**

```
$('#dynamic-menu li').each(function (index) {
  $(this).find("a").attr('href','#' + $('.cmsPanel:nth-child('+ (index+1) +')').attr('id'));
});
```

**After Edit**

```
$('#dynamic-menu li').each(function (index) {
  $(this).find("a").attr('href','#' + $('.cmsTabBox div:nth-of-type('+ (index+1) +')').attr('id'));
});
```

This way you can keep your link logic without repeating it for every link, and without using a incremental loop (`for`).

Next code is ow it would be rendered fixing some of error in the html structure/JavaScript :

```js
$(function () {
  $('#dynamic-menu li').each(function (index) {
    $(this).find("a").attr('href','#' + $('.cmsTabBox div:nth-of-type('+ (index+1) +')').attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dynamic-menu">
    <li><a href="/xxx">randomUrl</a></li>
    <li><a href="/yyy">another-random-url</a></li>
    <li><a href="/zzz">random</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="cmsTabBox">
    <ul></ul>
    <div id="randomUrl"></div>
    <div id="another-random-url"></div>
    <div id="random"></div>
</div>
```

What was missing ?

- You forgot to set the `id="dynamic-menu"` on the `ul` element.
- `cmsPanel` has changed into `cmsTabBox` in the JavaScript to match the HTML.
- I added `div:nth-of-type` to get the right children of the `cmsPanel`, as you wanted to get the children id and not the `cmsPanel` id.
- I added `nth-of-type` because apparently you could have another `ul` `li` list element in the `cmsPanel` div.

Comment: thank you... almost, but returns #undefined url for each

Comment: missing `()` `(index+1)`

Comment: Can you edit your question adding some HTML code ? Maybe the problem is the html structure.

Comment: Edited my answer, I will explain you what were the mistakes as well in a moment.

Comment: current answer still creates "#undefined" href value

Comment: Try refreshing the page and run the code snippet. I corrected the mistakes there.

Comment: YESYESYES! IT WORKS! THANK YOU VERY MUCH :)